# R: getGraphicsEvent behaves differently under windows and linux - especially mouse scroll

Tags: linux, windows, r, graphics

Under linux different mouse events are caught than under windows, see the output of the small test program below for the different events. I clicked once with each button. Under Linux I receive a button code for both, key down and release. Under Windows I do not receive an event at all when scrolling the wheel (which is a pity).

Is there a way under Windows to catch the scroll events using getGraphicsEvent()?

```
myplot <- function(...) {
    if (version$os == "linux-gnu")
       x11(type="Xlib")
    else
        x11()
    plot(...)

    mouse <- function(buttons, x, y) {
        cat("buttons:", buttons,"\n")
    }

    setGraphicsEventHandlers(onMouseDown = mouse, onMouseUp = mouse)
    eventEnv <- getGraphicsEventEnv()
} 
myplot(1:10)
getGraphicsEvent()
```

**Linux:**

left mouse button
 
buttons: 0
buttons: 0

middle mouse button (wheel)
buttons: 1
buttons: 1

right mouse button
buttons: 0 1
buttons: 0 1

wheel up
buttons: 2
buttons: 2

wheel down
buttons: 0 2
buttons: 0 2

**Windows:**

left mouse button
buttons: 0
buttons:

middle mouse button (wheel)
buttons: 1
buttons:

right mouse button
buttons: 2
buttons:

wheel up
no event

wheel down
no event

Answer (score 0):

The miscoded buttons have been fixed in [PR#16700](https://bugs.r-project.org/bugzilla3/show_bug.cgi?id=16700) to match the Windows results.

Comment: This answer is contradicted in 2022 (_six years_ later). The "buttons" argument seems to capture the _one_ button that _transitioned_ (from one state to the other). `plot(1);m=function(b,x,y)b;g=getGraphicsEvent;g(onMouseDown=m,onMouseUp=m);g(onMouseDown=m,onMouseUp=m)` version info: "platform: x86_64-conda-linux-gnu;  arch: x86_64;  os: linux-gnu;  system: x86_64, linux-gnu;  status:;  major: 4;  minor: 1.3;  year: 2022;  month: 03;  day: 10;  svn rev: 81868;  language: R;  version.string: **R version 4.1.3 (2022-03-10)**;  nickname: One Push-Up"